# Selecting units at different levels in multilevel modeling (HLM)

Tags: mixed-model

In order to fit multilevel model (HLM) in 3 level analysis can I select only one unit of analysis at level 2.

I mean to say that can i proceed in this way

(level 1)= students= 20 (From each school)
(level 2)= teacher = 01 (from each School)
(level 3)= schools= 50

or should it be better to exclude teacher from level 2 and thus

(level 1)= students= 20 (From each school)
(level 2)= schools= 50.

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated! Thank you for your question; I don't understand it exactly yet, but it does look like a valid question worth asking and answering here. May I suggest a few ways to improve your question, so that it attracts the most useful answer? Most importantly, please open your question with brief background on your *scientific* aims. What scientific question do you want to examine with your model? Also, you could help by making your question visually more organized and appealing, using the [markup](https://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help) facilities.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you do not have variability at level 2 (with only 1 teacher per school) and therefore cannot estimate a 3 level model in this data.